# How to only label every nth point on the x-axis of a line graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a line graph with around 150 'distance' points with associated dates for each point. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to only display every nth date, so they are currently an overlapping mess.

I've looked around and can only find examples dealing with numeric values on the x-axis, and my dates are characters.

Here is my code to generate the graph.

```
ggplot(data = bear.dist, aes(x = date, y = distance, group = 1))+
     geom_line(color = "#00AFBB", size = 1)
```

Here is my dataframe and graph.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Solution @Dave2e

```
 bear.dist$date <- as.Date(bear.dist$date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: Please do not include pictures of data. A better way to include the data in your post is to copy in the result of `dput(bear.dist)`.

Comment: Most likely is your date variable is a character or factor object, and not a date/time object.  Run `str(bear.dist)` to determine the class of each column.  There are plenty of examples here on stack overflow to convert from a string to a POSIXct object.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you! Once I converted the 'char' date column to Date/Time, it worked perfectly. Thank you.